# How do I specify ALL source node types in upgrade_d7_node_complete_book migration yaml

Tags: migrations

Drupal migrate_plus creates a default migration yaml for migrating books: upgrade_d7_node_complete_book.yml

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: upgrade_d7_node_complete_book
class: Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\D7NodeTranslation
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
  - 'Drupal 7'
  - Content
migration_group: migrate_drupal_7
label: 'Node complete (Book page)'
source:
  plugin: d7_node_complete
  node_type: book
```

As you see, the default source node_type is "book".  However, I would like to migrate ALL of my source content types to the Drupal 9 book content type.  How do I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done in [d7_node](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/4a30675b639a36ca528bd8b70e3efdb083a17c51/core/modules/node/src/Plugin/migrate/source/d7/Node.php)

```
 * @code
 * source:
 *   plugin: d7_node
 *   node_type: [page, test]
 * @endcode
 *
 * In this example nodes of type page and test are retrieved from the source
 * database.
```

I am assuming it holds true for d7_node_complete.